# How to use if/else condition on Django Templates?

Tags: django, templates, django-templates

I have the following dictionary passed to a render function, with sources being a list of strings and title being a string potentially equal to one of the strings in sources:

```
{'title':title, 'sources':sources})
```

In the HTML template I'd like to accomplish something among the lines of the following:

```
{% for source in sources %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ source }}</td>
    <td>
      {% if title == {{ source }} %}
        Just now!
      {% endif %}
    </td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

However, the following block of text results in an error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /admin/start/
Could not parse the remainder: '{{' from '{{'
```

...with `{% if title == {{ source }} %}` being highlighted in red.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

You shouldn't use the double-bracket `{{ }}` syntax within `if` or `ifequal` statements, you can simply access the variable there like you would in normal python:

```
{% if title == source %}
   ...
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Is this because of `if` or `ifequal`? or because of `{% %}` bracket?

Comment: same question: Is this specific to `if` and `for`? or because of `{% %}` bracket?

Comment: It's because of the `{%  %}` bracket. See this, and `{{  }}`, as an escape from HTML, allowing you to use python-like syntax and to access any variables sent via the template context.

Answer (score 45):

Sorry for comment in an old post but if you want to use an **else if** statement this will help you

```
{% if title == source %}
    Do This
{% elif title == value %}
    Do This
{% else %}
    Do This
{% endif %}
```

For more info see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#if

Comment: The link is broken. Can you fix please?

Answer (score 14):

```
{% for source in sources %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ source }}</td>
    <td>
      {% ifequal title source %}
        Just now!
      {% endifequal %}
    </td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}

                or


{% for source in sources %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ source }}</td>
        <td>
          {% if title == source %}
            Just now!
          {% endif %}
        </td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

[See Django Doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#ifequal)

Comment: this is now deprecated

Answer (score 3):

You **try** this.

I have already tried it in my **django template**.

It will work fine. Just remove the curly braces pair **{{** and **}}** from **{{source}}**.

I have also added **<table>** tag and ***that's it***.

After modification your **code** will look something like below.

```
{% for source in sources %}
   <table>
      <tr>
          <td>{{ source }}</td>
          <td>
              {% if title == source %}
                Just now! 
              {% endif %}
          </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
{% endfor %}
```

My dictionary looks like below,

```
{'title':"Rishikesh", 'sources':["Hemkesh", "Malinikesh", "Rishikesh", "Sandeep", "Darshan", "Veeru", "Shwetabh"]}
```

and **OUTPUT** looked like below once my **template** got rendered.

```
Hemkesh 
Malinikesh  
Rishikesh   Just now!
Sandeep 
Darshan 
Veeru   
Shwetabh
```