# Syntax to supply a parameter to a custom template tag in {% if %} block

Tags: django, django-templates

I have setup a custom template tag (simple_tag) (using https://stackoverflow.com/a/7716141/1369798) with a definition like this:

**templatetags/polls_extras.py**

```
def settings_value(name)
```

which I am able to use in my template like this:

**templates/index.html**

```
{% settings_value "ALLOWED_BOOL" %}
```

But this just inserts the text into my HTML output.

What is the syntax to use my template tag with parameter in an {% if %}?

I tried this but I get the error: *TemplateSyntaxError at / Unused '"ALLOWED_BOOL"' at end of if expression.*

**templates/index.html**

```
{% if settings_value ALLOWED_BOOL %}
You are allowed.
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11372177/django-template-tag-in-if-block but I want to add a parameter in!

Comment: Are you sure you can't sent this value to template from view? It seems not usual to set a new variable in template to use in it.

Comment: Nope... it's needed in every page. Have taken into accoubt discussion in http://stackoverflow.com/a/7716141/1369798 and this is the best solution... just want to know how to do it!

Comment: I think that better approach for you is a custom context processor. A custom context processor can 'inject' automatically new data to all templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a templatetag as a parameter to another templatetag. Your options here are either

1. modifying your `settings_value` templatetag so it can inject the value in the current context, ie :

   {% settings_value ALLOWED_BOOL as allowed_bool %}
   {% if allowed_bool %}
     You are allowed.
   {% endif %}

Note that `simple_tag` won't work here, you'll either have to switch to `assignement_tag` (if your Django version support it) - but then you'll loose the ability to directly output a setting in the template the way you actually do - or write a full blown custom templatetag (which is not as difficult as it might seem at first).

1. Use a custom context_processor instead like danhip suggests - but then only templates rendered using a `RequestContext` will access these variables.

Comment: Thanks Bruno.  I took your first option and created a new assignment_tag - works perfectly.