# If Statement - Django/Python

Tags: python, django, if-statement

I am trying to run a basic if statement in Django. I want to say that if the number inputted into the 'waist' text box is less than 100 then to output small if not output medium. My code is as follow;

```
{% block body %}
    <div class="container">
        <h1> Input Details </h1>
        {% for detail in input_detail %}
            <br>
            <br>
            Waist {{ detail.waist }}
            <br>
            <br>
        {% endfor %}
        {% if detail.waist <= 100 %}
            <p> small </p>
        {% else %}
            <p> Medium </p>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11372177/django-template-tag-in-if-block

Comment: Django, python cannot change the client side at input to the webpage without a request, meaning without a refresh. Which means you'd want to use javascript for that action. However if you are okay with page refreshing you can simply make a button that goes to `www.ws.com/?waist=x` and when user goes to that link it simply changes the `waist` to `x` on the server side

Answer (score 0):

You probably should look at some javascript solution and not django template to do a dynamic change like that.

With django what you vould do is a form with your input and have an other view get your result and displaying small or medium depending on yout input.