# Can't access a variable from django views.py in HTML page

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I know you can show a variable from the views.py using the `{{variable_name}}`

But my variable name is in an if statement:

So even when I type `{{variable_name}}` it doesn't show.

Rather it gets the else statement:
`variable_name = ''`

What could be the cause?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django -- Template tag in {% if %} block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11372177/django-template-tag-in-if-block)

Comment: Can you edit your question to show your code please.