# How do I create if statement on django template?

Tags: django

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HiNc.png)

If there are not projects created, projects is the name of my viewclass for my model, then I need it to create a message, but I do not know how to create the right if statement.

Comment: check if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/53040376/16004568

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard way to implement any `if` statement in Django's template:

```
{% if my_projects %}
    Do what you want if condition is ok
{% else %}
    Do what you want if condition is not satisfied
{% endif %}
```

I assume that `my_projects` variable contains a list/queryset of projects if any and is passed to the view's context.